# Typescript type narrowing using `in`

Tags: typescript

I was using typescript and want to check a field before using it. I used `in` to check its existence and than accessed it. However, I got the following error:

```js
function check(param: string) {
  // just check the type
}

type A = {
  a?: string
}

function q(a: A) {
  if ("a" in a) {
    check(a.a) // Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
  }
}
```

Since `"a" in a` returns true, "a" should exist in a and the error should not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's type narrowing does not recognize the "a" in a check as a guarantee that **a.a** is not **undefined**. The **in** operator checks for the presence of a property, but it doesn't narrow the type to exclude **undefined** in cases where the property is optional.

You could solve it by

1)

```
function q(a: A) {
  if (a.a !== undefined) {
    check(a.a)
  }
}
```

2. 

```
function q(a: A) {
  if ("a" in a && a.a !== undefined) {
    check(a.a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thought that "since `"a" in obj` is `true`, `obj.a` will have a value" is not quite right.

Enter this code in the developer tools:

```js
"a" in {a: undefined}
```

While `undefined` values are stripped in most representations of objects, they are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining (a?.a) to check if a.a is defined before passing it to the check function. This way, if a.a is undefined, the check function won't be called like:

```
function q(a: A){
if ("a" in a) {
check(a?.a); // Use optional chaining here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is you defined the `a` as optional and the `param` in your `check` function has a type of `string`. Basically, the type of `string` is not equal to the type of `string | undefined`

So you can use the [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) `??` operator to set a default value as a fallback.

```
function check(param: string) {
  // just check the type
}

type A = {
  a?: string
}

function q(a: A) {
  if ("a" in a) {
    check(a.a ?? "")
  }
}
```